# Display value of EditText in fragment of MainActivity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, sharedpreferences, preferences

I need to display a value of an EditTextpreference (Settings Activity) in TextView, which is in a Fragment of my MainActivity. I have tried several solutions already, my problem is mainly the saving of the value in a variable which is accessable by all activities. I have heard of two ways: intent extras and SharedPreferences. The problem is, in all tutorials I have seen the TextView is in the MainActivity and not the fragment of it, and the code I have tried is not working there. Here is my settings xml:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!--CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="example_checkbox"
        android:title="@string/pref_title_social_recommendations"
        android:summary="@string/pref_description_social_recommendations"
        android:defaultValue="true" /-->

    <!-- NOTE: EditTextPreference accepts EditText attributes. -->
    <!-- NOTE: EditTextPreference's summary should be set to its value by the activity code. -->
    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="example_text"
        android:title="@string/pref_title_display_name"
        android:defaultValue="@string/pref_default_display_name"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:inputType="textCapWords"
        android:capitalize="words"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:maxLength="25" />

    <!-- NOTE: Hide buttons to simplify the UI. Users can touch outside the dialog to
         dismiss it. -->
    <!-- NOTE: ListPreference's summary should be set to its value by the activity code. -->
    <ListPreference
        android:key="example_list"
        android:title="@string/pref_title_add_friends_to_messages"
        android:defaultValue="5"
        android:entries="@array/pref_example_list_titles"
        android:entryValues="@array/pref_example_list_values"
        android:negativeButtonText="@null"
        android:positiveButtonText="@null" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

And here is the fragment part of my MainActivity:

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {




    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        LayoutInflater lf = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View rootView = lf.inflate(R.layout.fragment_frontpage, container, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.NameView);
        textView.setText("Test");
        return rootView;
    }

}
```

So my main goal is to create a variable, which saves the value of the edittextpreference, which then is used in

```
textView.setText(Variable here);
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the preference values are stored in default shared preference files with respective keys:

```
     View rootView;
     onCreateView(){
        rootView=inflate(" inflate your view here");
        return rootView;

     }
     onResume(){
           TextView textView=(TextView)rootView.findViewById("your resource id here")
           SharedPreference pref=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreference(getActivity());
    String text=pref.getString("example_text","")
    textView.setText(text);

     }
```

Comment: the code seems to work, but the part with getString throws an error: cannot resolve symbol example_text. Could it be I somehow have to define it or create a locar variable?

Comment: Try now "example_text " is the key you have given as a key to your edit text preference

Comment: EDIT: yes this is working. Just one more expansion: the text changes only when the apk is loaded, that means if I go to the preferences activity, change the value and then back to the mainactivity, it doesnt change immediately. Could you please help me out with this?

Comment: @string/pref_default_display_name what there in this string

Comment: Are you extending a preference activity or preference fragment

Comment: Where are you calling set text if you doing it in on create move it to onresume

Comment: OK you are doing it in on create view move to code to onresume

Comment: View rootView make this a field rather than a local variable

Comment: is there a way to save it in sharedpreferences with onbackpressed in the settingsactivity?

Comment: The values are already saved but oncreateview is not being called on back pressed but on resume will be called on back pressed so you have to move your code to onresume

Comment: Well, I can only set the text of the TextView in the Fragment class.... how could I move the code to onResume()?

Comment: Check my answer now. Do the above in your fragment class

Comment: Did you add View rootView above onCreate and in Oncreate just say rootView=inflate() not View rootView=inflate()